# How to send e-mail using a remote server with CDOSYS

Tags: asp-classic

Can I use the configuration below? I think http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration was discontinued.

```
<%
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.server.com"
'Server port
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue with schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/.  What error message are you getting?  It's probably a case of you using incorrect configuration settings for the specific smtp server you are using - eg does it require authentication?  This page is useful - http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
<%
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.server.com"
'Server port
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _  
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "your-email-from-want-to-send-mail"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "your-email-password" 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.
Isn't because of the schema http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/ isn't available anymore?